# Apache UrlValidator for all scheme

Tags: java, url, url-validation

I am using `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator` for validating URL. It return true for http://www.google.com but false for www.google.com

I want to allow www.google.com also. I applied ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES as parameter but it is not working. How to customize UrlValidator so that it returns true for `www.google.com` and `http://localhost:8282/GFEReporting` also. Is there any way to customize this so it can take all schemes and no scheme? Please tell me.

or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: www.google.com is not a valid URL since it does not start with a scheme.

Answer (score 12):

```
UrlValidator validator = new UrlValidator() {
    /** allow missing scheme. */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value) {
        return super.isValid(value) || super.isValid("http://" + value);
    }
};

validator.validate("google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String value) {
    return UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid(value)
            || UrlValidator.getInstance().isValid("http://" + value);
}
```

This is simplified @Sergey's answer (without extending the `UrlValidator()` class).